# Can I pass google analytics marketing tracking code to a following page (when the landing page doesn't have GA code)

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, universal-analytics, web-analytics

I am in a scenario where we are tagging up on part of the site (purchase.mysite.com) with GA tags but we aren't tagging up the main site (www.mysite.com).

The problem is that a lot of traffic that goes to purchase.mysite.com initially goes via www.mysite.com which means if a user lands on www.mysite.com with a marketing tracking code and then goes to purchase.mysite.com the tracking code will be lost and all traffic from this route will be considered referral.

Is there a way to still pass this marketing campaign code when the user hits purchase.mysite.com (other than adding GA code to the main site which we don't want to do)?

If not possible in GA, is there another technical solution like saving the tracking code in the cookie and then setting it when the user goes to purchase.mysite.com?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Frank﻿

Answer (score 1):

Frank,

Your final paragraph htis the nail on the head: save your campaign tracking data into your own cookie and then read this cookie when you're on a page with GA on it and manually set the campaign data.  You only need to set it once and it will then propogate through for the whole session/user as per your requirements.

To set the campaign data manually, just use code such as this (ref: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#campaignName)

```
ga('set', 'campaignName', 'My Campaign Name');
ga('set', 'campaignSource', 'anotherwebsite.com');
ga('set', 'campaignMedium', 'cpc');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

**notes**

1. You must set at least Source & Medium for the data to register with GA
2. Medium has a fixed set of possible values as per this google doc: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033173?hl=en